# How to solve exception 'com_exception' with message 'Parameter 0: Type mismatch. ' in COM("Word.Application")

Tags: php, com, try-catch

I have try catch statement in php, but after running I am getting some error saying

> exception 'com_exception' with message 'Parameter 0: Type mismatch. '
>   in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\AutomationDocumentation\doccreation.php:218
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\AutomationDocumentation\doccreation.php(218):
>   variant->Open(false) #1 {main}

below is my code:

```
try{
   $word = new COM("Word.Application") or die ("Could not initialise Object.");
   // set it to 1 to see the MS Word window (the actual opening of the document)
   $word->Visible = 0;
   echo "Anish";
   $path=realpath("C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\AutomationDocumentation/$releasedoc/$releasedocfile.docx");
   //echo $path;
   // recommend to set to 0, disables alerts like "Do you want MS Word to be the default .. etc"
   $word->DisplayAlerts = 0;
   // open the word 2007-2013 document 
   $word->Documents->Open($path);
   $a="hello";
   // convert word 2007-2013 to PDF
  $word->ActiveDocument->ExportAsFixedFormat("C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\AutomationDocumentation\$created/$mainfolder/$releasedoc/$releasedocfile.pdf", 17, false, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, true, true, 2, true, true, false);
   // quit the Word process
   $word->Quit(false);
   // clean up
   unset($word);
}catch(Exception $e){
   echo $e;
}
```

Comment: i think file on  this path is not `$path=realpath("C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\AutomationDocumentation/$releasedoc/$releasedocfile.docx");` redable. change the doc permision, or put the doc in current working code directory and try

Comment: Hi Anant, I tried with current working code, its working fine , but in my code its  not working. Actually the word document I wanted to convert to PDF also creating using php only.

Comment: what i mean to say that put your doc file in the same directory where this code file is resist. And then directly gave the file name in `$path` and check once